# Why my option list are empty when using .map() in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I try to list some data on an option list with reactjs.

I have creat a const:

```
let [dealershipList, setDealershipList] = useState([props.dealerList]);

  const dealershipOptions = () => {
  return (
  dealershipList.map((data) => {
    return(
      <option value={data.id} key={data.id}>{data.name}</option>
    )}
  )
)
```

}

When I `console.log(dealershipList)` my data are present, but when I `console.log(data.id)` that's return `undefined`.

dealershipList contain an array like this:

```
    [Array(30)]
0: Array(30)
 0: {@id: "/dealers/1f37baca-08cc-4d47-88f8-77b390fd2f50", @type: "Dealer", id: "1f37baca-08cc-4d47-88f8-77b390fd2f50", dealerCode: "70839", name: "Dealer1", …}
 1: {@id: "/dealers/197676fd-693e-4638-89e2-048d1d04d10e", @type: "Dealer", id: "197676fd-693e-4638-89e2-048d1d04d10e", dealerCode: "70916", name: "Dealer2", …}
 2: {@id: "/dealers/1bc5b10a-529e-42e5-b50e-0d8933d19844", @type: "Dealer", id: "1bc5b10a-529e-42e5-b50e-0d8933d19844", dealerCode: "70908", name: "Dealer3", …}
 3: {@id: "/dealers/04796a76-b282-4fd5-9699-f471ac7c8a93", @type: "Dealer", id: "04796a76-b282-4fd5-9699-f471ac7c8a93", dealerCode: "71081", name: "dealer4", …}
```

I call my const in html like this:

```
<div className="form-group">
   <label htmlFor="dealership">
      {t('Dealership')}
   </label>
 <select className="form-control" value={dealership} onChange={(e) => setDealership(e.target.value)}>
      {
       dealershipOptions()
      }
  </select>
</div>
```

This code is on a modal, when I open my modal, the field select dealership is empty.

Do you know why ?

Comment: so when this method runs `dealershipOptions()` if you console.log there, does the output show an empty array or the array you posted?

Comment: Looks like the issue is here `useState([props.dealerList]);`. Change it to `useState(props.dealerList);`

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya it's perfect, thanks you